# How to center my barcode with itext on a pdf

Tags: java, itext

I use IText to make a barcode on a pdf and i don't know how to center this barcode.

This is my code

```
para = new Paragraph(nom_ecole,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD,45));
para.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
document.add(para);
para = new Paragraph(nom_eleve1+" "+prenom_eleve1,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD,45));
para.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
document.add(para);
codebarre.setCodeType(Barcode.EAN8);
codebarre.setCode(id_doss1);
document.add(codebarre.createImageWithBarcode(cb,BaseColor.BLACK,BaseColor.BLACK));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You need to calculate the coordinates of the page by width and height 
May be it will help you..

Long width=(long) pdfReader.getPageSize(i).getWidth();
Long height=(long) pdfReader.getPageSize(i).getHeight();

if (pdfReader.getPageRotation(i) % 180 == 0) {
                        x = width / 2;
                        y = height - 20;
                    }
                    else {
                        x = width / 2;
                        y = height - 20;
                    }

ColumnText.showTextAligned(pdfStamper.getOverContent(i), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, header, x, y+3, 0);
```